# How do I mock an OAuth2Authentication Object in Spring Test

Tags: spring-security, spring-test, spring-boot-actuator

I would like to test my rest controller in spring. In my the service, a user requires to pass an authentication token. I use a token utils class that decodes the token and get an organization id. I then use the id for several processes. How do I do a mock of this in Spring? I have followed [this](https://www.baeldung.com/oauth-api-testing-with-spring-mvc) documentation but am getting a 404 on running the test.

**TodoController**

````
@RequestMapping("todos")
class TodoController {

    @Autowired
    lateinit var todoService: TodoService

    @Autowired
    lateinit var tokenUtils: TokenUtils

    @GetMapping
    fun getAllTodos(authentication: OAuth2Authentication): ResponseEntity<List<Todo>> {
        tokenUtils.init(authentication);
        val organizationId = tokenUtils.organizationId
        return ResponseEntity.ok(todoService.findAll(organizationId))
    }```

I am a bit new to spring tests and will appreciate any help accorded
````

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create a mock Authentication class that implements Authentication interface. Most of following code is auto generated. Override any method you you need (in this case, I only override getPrincipal method).

```
import java.util.Collection;

import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;

public class MockPrincipal implements Authentication {

    public MockPrincipal() {}

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getCredentials() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getDetails() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getPrincipal() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return "mock user";
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAuthenticated() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void setAuthenticated(boolean isAuthenticated) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }



}
```

After that you can mock up an OAuth2Authentication object like this:

```
MockPrincipal mockUser = new MockPrincipal();
OAuth2Authentication mockOAuth2Object = new OAuth2Authentication(null, mockUser);
```

Comment: Is the override considered best practices?